# Able to Build Unreal Project, Unable to Open Unreal Project

Tags: unreal-engine5

I was attempting to rename an Unreal tutorial project and for sake of consistency wanted to change the name of the uproject and .sln file to match, figuring I could just change them back if it broke anything.

Well it did break things and I'm unable to get unreal to open the project now. Here are the errors I get when I attempt to open it:

[image: The following modules are missing or built with a different engine version: Obstacle Assault]
[image: ObstacleAssault could not be compiled. Try rebuilding from source manually.]

However I then open the project in Visual Studio 2022 and it does successfully build.

[image: Successful building of project.]

- I have changed the names back to the original value.
- I have regenerated the project files.
- I only have one version of Unreal installed 5.0.2.
- I have deleted and recreated the Binaries, Intermediate, and Saved folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the contents of the save folder? you may be able to drag n drop the .Uproject file and open up the project.

If this doesn't work i recommend just starting a new project and copy and paste your content folder and redo the necessary work to link it up - IE Input, Plugins, world level blueprints, etc.

Comment: you should answer after receving an answer your question. You can ask it as a comment under the question

Comment: I restarted the project from scratch and no longer have the broken code. Thank you though!